# how do i change my account name in the users file?

Tags: user, file-location

I need to change my account name because some programs I need to use won't allow me to save things in a file location with a # in the name. however my user name is FBI VAN #1 so the location always at least has this in it.

C:\Users\FBI VAN #1\

I've looked through so many guides on how to change it, but all i can find are ways to change the more visable account name in the windows bar. if i can get some instructions that would be great.

Comment: which version of windows do you use? please add it as a tag of you question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your edition, try the following options:

1) Hit "Win+R" and type in "lusrmgr.msc" If you can, renaming the account here is foolproof (can't exactly give the procedure, as my system doesn't have this option, but you have to rename it somewhere in properties, I think)

2) Run using elevated prompt and restart

```
wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename newname
```

Example: To rename the user account ‘xpuser’ as ‘win7user’ we can run the below command.

```
wmic useraccount where name='xpuser' rename win7user
```

3) Try changin it in User Accounts in Control Panel (probably won't work)

4) Create a new account and migrate all data to it (last option)